# Make Docker container take memory as needed without a cap

Tags: docker

I'm developing an app which needs a lot of memory, and I'm running it in a Docker container.

If I pass `--memory=64g` to the `docker run` command, the memory available to the container is still fixed at 8gb (determined by running `grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo` from inside the container). I have to open Docker Desktop and go in the settings and set the Resources available to be 64gb to fix this. But then it looks like Docker is claiming all of this memory and it is no longer available to the host system - if I assign all the memory that my computer has, Docker Desktop takes some time to try and claim all the memory and then crashes.

Is there a way I can just make the Docker container take as much memory as it needs on an ongoing basis without having to remove that memory from being used by the host computer?

Comment: What's your host OS?  A container by default can use all of the memory available to the host system, but Docker Desktop always runs in a Linux VM and you're limited by its capacity.  If you're on native Linux, using Docker directly without Docker Desktop will get around this.

Comment: yep, I'm on native Linux. I'll try running it without Docker Desktop, thanks